# Dependency injection annotations RESTful service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I have a classic DAO and Service layer. For both I have interfaces. 
Service layer is annoteted with `@WebService`, then I also have layer for RESTful crud methods.
I want to use Dependency injection for DAO and Services. I don't know which annotations should use to inject Service into RESTful service.

Here is snippet:

```
 @Path("/items")
  public class ItemsResource{

      @Context
      UriInfo uriInfo;
      @Context
      Request request;

          //annotations....
      private IService itemService;

       public ItemsResource(IService itemService){
       this.itemService=itemService;
        }
            //methods...
```

So my question is how would I inject itemService into my RESTful service? Which annotation should I use?
I' don't use Spring Framework.

Comment: Do you have a *beans.xml* file in your WEB-INF?

Comment: No I dont have. I guess this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with `@Inject` of [JSR330](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) ?

Some of the frameworks that you may want to check (other than spring):

- [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)
- [Silkdi](http://www.silkdi.com/)
- [picocontainer](http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Yes I have tried but I get nullPointer. I only use `@Inject` and `@Named` for bean? Should I use some other annotations?